# Vue / Vue-bulma - nprogress: Progress bar loads forever on guard/redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

nprogress works just fine in every other regard, but on redirect to /login it spins forever. I've attempted the showProgressBar: false to no avail.

If user is logged in they'll be redirected to /dashboard, if they are not they will be redirected to /login.

My code looks like this:

```
const routes = [
  {path: '/', name: 'root', redirect: { name: 'login' }, meta: {showProgressBar: false}},
  {path: '/login', component: LoginPage, name: 'login', beforeEnter: loggedIn, meta: {showProgressBar: false}},
  {path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardPage, name: 'dashboard', meta: { requiresAuth: true }},
  {path: '/editor', component: PhoneEditorPage, name: 'editor', meta: { requiresAuth: true }},
  {path: '/usersettings', component: PinPasswordPage, name: 'pinpassword', meta: { requiresAuth: true }},
  {path: '/callforwarding', component: CallForwardingPage, name: 'callforwarding', meta: { requiresAuth: true }},
  { name: 'dropdown', path: '/dropdown', component: Dropdown, meta: { requiresAuth: true  }}
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  mode: 'hash',
  routes
})

function loggedIn (to, from, next) {
  const authUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
  if (authUser && authUser.auth) {
    next({name: 'dashboard'})
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    const authUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
    if (authUser && authUser.auth) {
      next()
    } else {
      next({name: 'login'})
      this.nprogress.done()
    }
  }
  next()
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle on this?

Comment: That's not really feasible with all my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't simple to answer without see code in action, but, you can try to invert call to `this.nprogess.done()` and `next(...)` like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    const authUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
    if (authUser && authUser.auth) {
      next()
    } else {
      this.nprogress.done(); // <- HERE
      next({name: 'login'})
    }
  }
  next()
}
```

since next() call move context to new component, and I'm not sure call to nprogress will be called on the right moment.